# Несколько вопросов по ASP.MVC и AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Я только разбираюсь в `ASP.MVC` и может быть задаю глупые вопросы.
В данном случае вопросы будут не "как сделать", а "почему так происходит".
Делаю проект, суть которого заключается в том, что он обходит сайт, собирает ссылки на его страницы и  измеряет время отклика. Потом, собранную информацию выводит в табличном виде (пока).
Проект состоит из двух страниц. На первой - в соответствующем инпуте водится поле и по нажатию кнопки идет переход на другой контроллер (`ToolController`), который  производит замеры и выводит результаты.

Код метода первого контроллера (`HomeController`):

```
public ActionResult Submit(string Url)
{
    if (CheckUrl(Url))
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tool", new { Url });
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Некорректный адрес!"; 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

Валидацию пока можно не смотреть, это буду отдельно разбираться.

Представление (фрагмент):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Введите адрес сайта в поле ввода и нажмите кнопку")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBox("Url")
            </td>
            <td>@ViewBag.Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Отправить запрос"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Во `ToolController` есть поле  `private` поле класса `VMManager`, методы которого реализуют бизнес-логику. В классе `VMManager` есть поле вью-модели (`VM`), потому что все дальнейшие действия будут крутиться вокруг один раз построенной `VM` (сохранение в БД -  пока не реализовано).
Представление выводит таблицу, состоящую из ссылок на страницы сайта (`Ajax.ActionLink`), по нажатию на которые  должно подгружаться `partialView` с графическим представлением информации.
До графического представления мне пока далеко,  пока разобраться бы что в табличном происходит.

Фрагмент контроллера (`ToolController`):

```
 private static VMManager manager = new VMManager();

    public ToolController()
    {
       // manager = new VMManager();
    }
    // GET: Tool
    public ActionResult Index(string url)
    {
       // manager = new VMManager();
        manager.VM = (SiteVM)manager.GetVM(url);

        return View(manager.VM);
    }

    public ActionResult ShowPageResultInChart(string pattern)
    {
        if (pattern == "test") return null;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return PartialView("ShowPageResultInChart");
    }
```

Фрагмент представления:

```
@Html.Action("ShowPageResultInChart", new { pattern ="test" })
```

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.PageResults)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Ajax.ActionLink(item.PageAddress, "ShowPageResultInChart", new {pattern= item.PageAddress },
             new AjaxOptions
             {
                 UpdateTargetId = "ChartData",
                 LoadingElementId = "LoadingIndicator"
             }
                )
            </td>



            <td>@item.MinTime</td>
            <td>@item.AverageTime</td>
            <td>@item.MaxTime</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

В частичном представлении пока смотреть нечего: строчка "Сработал `Ajax`"
Теперь вопросы:

1. Если верить отладчику, то при первичной загрузке основной страницы  запускается метод `ShowPageResultInChart`. Хотя он предполагался к запуску только при нажатии на `Ajax.ActionLink`. Почему, что я сделал не так? От этой беды я избавился условием в методе `ShowPageResultInChart`, но почему он срабатывает? Я правильно понимаю, что это противоречит смыслу `Ajax`?
   Разместить его ниже таблицы я не могу по условиям задания.  Причем у меня сложилось впечатление, что запускается он как минимум 2 раза, но может я ошибаюсь.
2. Судя по всему, у меня запускается несколько экземпляров второго контроллера. Это я понял по тому, что `VM` в процессе обнуляется и при нажатии на `Ajax.ActionLink` на входе метода `ShowPageResultInChart VM = null`. Такое впечатление, что первый экземпляр создается при выводе таблицы, второй -  при нажатии на `Ajax.ActionLink`. От этой беды я избавился сделав поле менеджера статическим, но почему так происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `ShowPageResultInChart` вы вызываете не только с помощью `@Ajax.ActionLink`, а также с помощью `@Html.Action`, отсюда он и выполняется при загрузке страницы.

```
@Html.Action("ShowPageResultInChart", new { pattern ="test" })
```

2) При каждом запросе создается отдельный экземпляр класса Controller через [ControllerFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx).

Обратите внимание, что `Html.Action` Html Helper создаст другой экземпляр контроллера.

В общем, `ControllerActivator.Create` вызывается (для каждого запроса), чтобы создать контроллер (который создает новый контроллера или через DependencyResolver или через Activator, если не Resolver не был установлен):

```
public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
        try {
            return (IController) (_resolverThunk().GetService(controllerType) ? ? Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType));
        }
```

Comment: "Обратите внимание, что Html.Action Html Helper создаст другой контроллер." Вы имеете в виду еще один экземпляр контроллера?

Comment: да, еще один экземпляр контроллера

Comment: @foxhound обновил ответ